# How does molar volume change as the number of moles of gaseous mixture increase in same volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, physical-chemistry, ideal-gas

Consider this reaction:

$$PCl_5<=>PCl_3+Cl_2$$

Suppose, I have a closed chamber filled with only PCl5 gas. Now, after some time, PCl3 and Cl2 will be produced. Now, the total mole number of the gaseous mixture at equilibrium will be greater than the total mole number when there was only PCl5 present. Graphically,

[image]

Suppose, the volume of the chamber is 20L. Now, if 5mol of gas was present initially (when there was only PCl5), suppose there would be 7.5 mol of gas present at equilibrium (comprising of PCl5, PCl3 & Cl2).

So,

molar volume initially, $m_1=\frac{20}{5}Lmol^{-1}=4Lmol^{-1}$

molar volume finally/at equilibrium, $m_2=\frac{20}{7.5}Lmol^{-1}=2.6667Lmol^{-1}$

So, $$m_1>m_2$$

So, we can say that the molar volume has decreased.

However, my book states the opposite.

> The number of moles increases in the dissociation of PCl5. Meaning, **the molar volume of the gas mixture increases**; therefore, in the closed chamber, due to this reaction, the pressure of the gaseous mixture increases at the same volume.

What mistake am I making to understand the book?

Answer (score 2):

The molar volume is not determined by the volume of the chamber. It is a characteristic of the gas for specific pressure and temperature. If the pressure increases, at the same temperature, the molar volume increases even though the volume of the chamber does not. The reasoning in the book is backwards in my opinion. If you increase the number of particles the pressure increases so the molar volume increases. Just from an increase in the number of moles you cannot say that the molar volume has increased or decreased. It depends on the change in the parameters of the gas (pressure and temperature). Maybe theirs is the chemists way of thinking about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I had another question. Is there a difference between the change in molar volume of an ideal gas when the pressure is increased (i) by decreasing the volume and (ii) by increasing pressure at the same volume i.e. by increasing the number of moles of gas?

Comment: I posted another [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681092/260477) very related to this topic. If you want, you can check it out!