# Difficulty understanding molar volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, physical-chemistry, ideal-gas

Suppose I am at STP and I am dealing with an ideal gas and I have a 22.4L container (with a movable piston attached on top) filled with 1 mol gas. Now, I will try to change the molar volume in two ways:

**Way 1**

If I increase the pressure exerted on the ideal gas by decreasing the volume of the container, the molar volume will decrease.

**Way 2**

If I increase the pressure exerted on the ideal gas by injecting 1 mol more gas in the cylinder keeping the volume of the container constant (22.4L), the molar volume will change (I think). I think the molar volume will decrease.

Is my prediction right in way 2? If yes, then why am I not able to apply it [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681051/260477)?

If my prediction in way 2 is wrong, could you please tell me why I am wrong?

Comment: It must be a typo in your book

Comment: Right? I thought that too, so I saw another book, and the same thing was written. I'm so confused.

Comment: Well,,with all due respect to your books, they’re wrong.

Comment: Could you share the name of your book and pg number (preferably link though)

Comment: @ChetMiller If you provide an answer, I will award the bounty to you kind sir.

Comment: I don't do this for reputation points.  I do this only to help people.  I'm glad my answers were of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Molar volume is defined by:
$V_m=M/\rho$. M is molar mass , and $\rho$ is the density.

Molar mass dosent change.

In both cases $\rho$ increases leading to a lower molar volume.